# Cómo hacer que mi bot de discord con python se conecte a un canal de voz con un comando?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

Tengo dos archivos, uno que se llama responses.py que es este:

```
import random
import discord

def get_response(message: str) -> str:
    p_message = message.lower()

    if p_message == 'hola':
        return 'Hola, qué tal?'

    if p_message == 'tira un dado':
        dado=str(random.randint(1, 6))
        return (f'Sacaste `{dado}`!')
    
    if p_message == 'tira un dado de 10 caras':
        dado=str(random.randint(1, 9))
        return (f'Sacaste `{dado}`!')
    
    if p_message == 'twitch':
        return 'El twitch de <@ejemplodeusuario> es `https://www.twitch.tv/<un canal de twitch>`'

    if p_message == 'intento':
        return 'Funcionó :smile:'
    
    if p_message== 'connect':
        return 'Se supone que me uní al canal de voz'

    if p_message== 'disconnect':
        return 'se supone que me desconecté del canal de voz'
    
    if p_message == 'ayuda':
        return """**Los comandos de este servidor son:**
        `hola` si copias hola, el bot te saludará
        `tira un dado` si pones !tira un dado, el bot lanzará un dado de 6 caras por ti
        `twitch` si copias !twitch el bot te mostará el canal de McDalle
        `ayuda` el bot te mostrará este texto
        `intento` si copias intento, el bot te dirá Funcionó :smile:
        """
    
    return '**Ups! no reconocí ese comando** No olvides el espacio entre el prefijo `Wh!` y lo que le quieres pedir al bot, si tienes problemas, copia `Wh! ayuda`'
```

y otro que se llama bot.py y es este:

```
import discord
import datetime
import responses
import discord.voice_client
from config import Config
from discord.ext import commands


TOKEN = Config.TOKEN

async def send_message(message, user_message, is_private):
    try:
        response = responses.get_response(user_message)
        await message.author.send(response) if is_private == True else await message.channel.send(response)

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

def prender_bot1():
    Intents = discord.Intents().all()
    bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='Wh!', intents=Intents)

    @bot.event
    async def on_ready():
        print(f'{bot.user.name} está conectado a los siguientes servidores:')
        for guild in bot.guilds:
            print(f'- {guild.name} (id: {guild.id})')
        print("\n")
        
            
    @bot.event
    async def on_message(message):
        if message.author.bot:
            return
        else:
            user_message = str(message.content).lower()

            if user_message.startswith('Wh! '):
                user_message = user_message[4:]

                if message.guild is not None:
                    username = str(message.author)
                    channel = str(message.channel)
                    user_id= str(message.author.id)
                    server_name = str(message.guild.name)
                    canal_de_voz=message.author.voice.channel
                    print(f'{username} con el id {user_id} dijo: "{user_message}" en el canal: ({channel}), en el servidor "{server_name}"')
                    await send_message(message, user_message, is_private=False)
                    """
                    if user_message=='connect':
                        await canal_de_voz.connect()
                    elif user_message=='disconnect':
                        await canal_de_voz.disconnect()
                    """
                else:
                    user_id= str(message.author.id)
                    username = str(message.author)
                    print(f'{username} con el id {user_id} dijo: "{user_message}" al bot por privado')
                    await send_message(message, user_message, is_private=True)

    bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Y quiero hacer que el bot se conecte a un canal de voz cuando use el comando Wh! connect en lugar de que simplemente salga 'Se supone que me uní al canal de voz' o 'se supone que me desconecté del canal de voz'.
he intentado muchas formas de hacerlo, pero ninguna me funciona puesto que requieren que modifique el archivo *bot.py* (que no es lo ideal) y en algunas me ha funcionado, pero dejan de funcionar los comandos que tengo en *responses.py*.

He intentado con algo como esto:

```
@bot.command()
async def join(ctx):
    # Verifica si el usuario está en un canal de voz
    if ctx.author.voice:
        # Se une al canal de voz
        channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
        voice_client = await channel.connect()
        await ctx.send(f"Me he unido al canal de voz {channel}.")
    else:
        await ctx.send("Debes estar en un canal de voz para utilizar este comando.")
```

También con algo como esto:

```
 @bot.event
    async def on_message(message):
        if message.author.bot:
            return
        else:
            user_message = str(message.content).lower()

            if user_message.startswith('Wh! '):
                user_message = user_message[4:]

                if message.guild is not None:
                    username = str(message.author)
                    channel = str(message.channel)
                    user_id= str(message.author.id)
                    server_name = str(message.guild.name)
                    canal_de_voz=message.author.voice.channel
                    print(f'{username} con el id {user_id} dijo: "{user_message}" en el canal: ({channel}), en el servidor "{server_name}"')
                    await send_message(message, user_message, is_private=False)
                    
                    if user_message=='connect':
                        await canal_de_voz.connect()
                    elif user_message=='disconnect':
                        await canal_de_voz.disconnect()
                    
                else:
                    user_id= str(message.author.id)
                    username = str(message.author)
                    print(f'{username} con el id {user_id} dijo: "{user_message}" al bot por privado')
                    await send_message(message, user_message, is_private=True)
```

pero como decía, ambas ideas son modificando el archivo *bot.py* y no quiero modificarlo, además que ninguna de estas ideas funcionó y no encuentro información en la web que me diga cómo puedo conectar al bot por medio del otro archivo *responses.py*

entonces mi pregunta es: ¿hay alguna forma en la que pueda conectar al bot a un canal de voz modificando solo el archivo responses.py para que cuando use los comandos Wh! connect y Wh! disconnect se conecte y desconecte de él respectivamente?

Comment: "¿Hay alguna forma en la que pueda conectar al bot a un canal de voz modificando solo el archivo responses.py?": No, no la hay. Esto se debe a que a la función `get_response()` le estás pasando únicamente el contenido (`content`) del mensaje (`str`) lo que impide que puedas obtener información necesaria como pueden ser el miembro que envió el mensaje, el canal de voz en el que se encuentra o el servidor en cuestión. Tendrías que definir un método nuevo en `responses.py` que reciba la información necesaria y, como mínimo, modificar `bot.py` para que se llame a dicha función.